# Adobe Director 12 simple hyperlink

Tags: adobe, lingo

I am looking for the simplest syntax to make an image or text into a hyperlink within Adobe Director 12.

Here are two reference links:

[Creating a hypertext link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Director/11.5/UsingScripting/WS6F8870C2-0BB5-462f-899F-2386AB05D637.html)

[on hyperlinkClicked](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Director/11.5/UsingScripting/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811d64c1a1b3-7d03.html)

Do I need a `hyperlinkClicked` event handler, or is there a simpler way? I am new to Lingo.